# What is the best way to get optimal processing power?

Tags: dns, motherboard, xeon

I am building a 'server computer' for my house.  I wonder if it is better to buy two Intel [Xeon E3-1240](http://ark.intel.com/products/75055/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1240-v3-8M-Cache-3_40-GHz) V3 processors and run them on the same motherboard, or to buy an Ivy bridge-e processor, like the [4930](http://ark.intel.com/products/75133/Intel-Core-i7-4930MX-Processor-Extreme-Edition-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz?q=4930) that is coming out in the next 2 days?

My plan is to do self hosting at home and I will be running multiple servers in order to use up all the cores and threads. If I want to build the computer with the best processing power that can run day and night, what setup should I go with? Mind you I bought two WD Reds for constant read-write.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It almost never makes sense to do serious hosting at home. It's *much* cheaper and more practical to bring the processing power to the bandwidth than to bring the bandwidth to the processing power.

Comment: Trevor, the help documents are pretty clear that anything in a home environment is off-topic for SF (http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).  I beg you to read them before asking any further questions, and not to take it personally if this gets closed.

Comment: Who says the server can not be in home? I mean Its still a server, weather it's in a rack or on a desk right?

Comment: Random tidbit: A motherboard for two CPU's (with intergrated memory controllers in the CPU) usually means up to twice memory capacity and bandwidth.

Comment: @TrevorRudolph, the ServerFault help page and on-topic list explicitly mentions that you cannot ask about "Anything in a home or development environment". A server may be a server, but if it's cobbled together running on home networks and power your SLA is going to be nowhere as good as running it in a datacenter. If you're in New York I expect there's a dozen colocation or dedicated server providers quite close to you. My advice? Buy, not build, and colocate it.

Comment: Trevor, I removed the second question; questions asking for advice like this is just asking for opinion based answers and will possibly mean your question will be closed. You can of course undo my change :). My suggestion is, go to current providers (LunarPages, FastHosts, 1and1, NetworkSolutions etc) and check out the spec of the dedicated servers (or even VPS) then you'll get an idea how much power you'll actually need... It could be that either configuration will be suitable to you.

Comment: You forgot to mention what you're going to be running on the server. It's pretty much impossible to even guess without knowing this.

Comment: Unless this is purely for hosting stuff originating from within your home you'll almost certainly be better off renting blades.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the linked Intel ARK page,

```
Max CPU Configuration   1
```

E3 1240v3s *cannot* be run in a multi-socket configuration; they don't have enough QPIs for that. So your other option is a lot more likely for sure.

To repeat what the other folks from serverfault said, self-hosting at home is almost always a bad idea. The amount of money you'll spend on power (figure 110W for a light to medium loaded server = 85KWH/month -> ~12.6 USD @$0.15 per KWH), plus the amount you'll need to spend on bandwidth (depends on application, but I would imagine >50 USD/mo increase, especially when you switch to a business plan that allows for server hosting in the AUP) will almost always exceed colocation cost. A 1U colo will probably cost you between 60 and 100 USD at a middle of the road datacenter.

Comment: Ah, I didn't check the edit log; rephrased.